# cucumber step_definitions Q on style/approach on I should see

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'd like to get opinions from others with more experience on writing Cucumber step definitions.
My initial intention was to verify that a particular link was present in one scenario and
verify that it wasn't present in another scenario.

So I have the following two steps. In my naivety I thought I could use the '!find_link(...)'.
In the end I decided to use exceptions.
I'd like to solicit feedback on two aspects:
1. the approach I've taken on using the exceptions within the step_definition
2. is it meaningful to expect to explicitly look for links in the rendered page?

As I finished up work last night I couldn't help thinking "why didn't I simply use:
I should not see 'Sign up'?" and this morning it dawned on me that 'Sign up' could be included in a paragraph on the page somewhere.

Here are the steps, thanks in advance...

```
Then /^I should see link: ?"([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
    find_link("#{link}")
end

Then /^I should not see link: ?"([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
#    !find_link("#{link}") - commented out because it won't fail if link is present
    begin
          find_link("#{link}")
      raise FindException
    rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Then' step definitions definition should always contain an assertion, e.g. *should* if using RSpec or *assert* if using Test::Unit.

So if want you want to verify a specific URL isn't present, it would be better to do:

```
should_not have_link(link)
```

However, it would probably be better to re-write the step as:

```
Then I should not see a sign-up option
```

And in the step definition, rather than checking for a URL, you could check for a link with a particular class:

```
should_not have_css('a.signup')
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. You answer has been very helpful. I wasn't aware of the have_link() and found very useful siblings when I searched for it.
I think I see what you're saying about a better way to re-write the step. I've started to write more declarative rather than imperative steps based on this article [link]http://benmabey.com/2008/05/19/imperative-vs-declarative-scenarios-in-user-stories.html that was recommended in web_steps.rb